How to fix Nvim 'E5113: Error while calling lua chunk'?
I tried to install Telescope and Treesitter plugins in my Nvim, but when I open Nvim I get this error message:

Error detected while processing /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/keymap.lua:0: rhs: expected string|function, got nil
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
vim/shared.lua: in function 'validate'
vim/keymap.lua: in function 'set'
.../user/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugin_config/telescope.lua:4: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
/home/user/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugin_config/init.lua:5: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
[nvim-treesitter] [0/7] Downloading tree-sitter-markdown_inline...
Press ENTER or type command to continue


-- ~/.config/nvim/init.lua
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)


require("core.keymaps")
require("core.plugins")
require("core.plugin_config")

-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugins.lua
require("lazy").setup({
   'ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim',
   'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua',
   'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons',
   'nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim',
   'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter',
   {
   'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.8',
   dependencies = { {'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'} }
    },
})

-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugin_config/init.lua
require("core.plugin_config.gruvbox")
require("core.plugin_config.lualine")
require("core.plugin_config.nvim-tree")
require("core.plugin_config.treesitter")
require("core.plugin_config.telescope")

-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugin_config/telescope.lua
local builtin = require('telescope.builtin')

vim.keymap.set('n', '<c-p>', builtin.find_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Space><Space>', builtin.old_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Space>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Space>fh', builtin.help_tags, {})

-- ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/plugin_config/treesitter.lua
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
  -- A list of parser names, or "all" (the listed parsers MUST always be installed)
  ensure_installed = { "c", "lua", "vim", "vimdoc", "query", "markdown", "markdown_inline", "html", "css", "javascript" },
  -- Install parsers synchronously (only applied to `ensure_installed`)
  sync_install = false,
  auto_install = true,
  highlight = {
    enable = true,
  },
}

I tried this The Lua error:"E5113: Error while calling lua chunk:xattempt to call fiel d 'setup' (a nil value)", but it didn't work.
When i remove the Telescope and Treesitter plugins, Nvim starts working again.
So how can I fix this problem?

There might be a call to setup(...) somewhere in one of these file:

require("core.plugin_config.treesitter")
require("core.plugin_config.telescope")

Double check for typos, maybe around require('telescope').setup(...)
If you post the content of these 2 files, and if they are too big, at least the lines around setup() would work.

Thanks for your answer! I added the Telescope and Treesitter files to my question.
